# Select all elemtnts in class but not current target

Tags: javascript

How to select all elements in class by index ( or... I don't what else, just learning js :) ) but not current target? To avoid this ->

```
var menu_page = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_page')[0];
var menu_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_btn')[0];
var menu_list = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_list');
var menu_item = document.getElementsByClassName('menu_item');
var front = document.getElementsByClassName('front');
var back = document.getElementsByClassName('back');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    menu_page.classList.toggle('menu_page_out');
    menu_btn.classList.toggle('menu_btn_out');
});

menu_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    menu_page.classList.toggle('menu_page_out_full');
    menu_btn.classList.toggle('menu_btn_out_full');
    for (var a = 0; a < menu_item.length; a++) {
        menu_item[a].addEventListener('click', function(){
            this.classList.toggle("flipped");
            switch(this.id) {
                case 'a':
                    back[0].classList.toggle.("grow_2");
                    front[0].classList.toggle("grow_2");
                    menu_list[0].classList.toggle("grow");
                    front[1].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                    menu_list[1].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                    front[2].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                    menu_list[2].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                    front[3].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                    menu_list[3].classList.toggle("slide_left");
                break;
                case 'b':

                break;
                case 'c':

                break;
                case 'd':

                break;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I want to avoid typing class[index number] for each case.

Comment: So basically, you want to use `document.getElementByClassName("[CLASS]")` and then filter out `event.currentTarget` in some event handler?

Comment: Yes, I want filter out current target. I'll post code that I have for now  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `item_1` is `menu_list[0]` in your example, I think you're probably looking for:

```
menu_list.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.classList.toggle(entry === this ? "slide_right" : "slide_left");
}, this);
```

That loops through the array of entries, toggling classes, checking each entry against `this` (the current entry). Note that I'm passing `this` as a second argument to `forEach` (after the function), so that `this` within the callback is the same as `this` outside it.

In ES6, I'd do it with an arrow function instead:

```
menu_list.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.classList.toggle(entry === this ? "slide_right" : "slide_left");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of your example! Something new for me, for my lvl of knowledge )